# Query logical processing phases while mixing old and new join syntax

Tags: query

Could anyone clarify why order of tables in `FROM` matters if I mix old and new syntax for joining tables? 
For example,

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 a, table2 b
INNER JOIN table3 c ON (c.a_id = a.id) -- error - a.id - invalid identifier
WHERE (a.id = b.a_id)

SELECT * 
FROM table2 b, table1 a 
INNER JOIN table3 c ON (c.a_id = a.id) -- ok, table1 a is the last in FROM
WHERE (a.id = b.a_id)
```

I'm not going to use such ugly queries, but I believe all tables specified in `FROM` should be visible to other parts of the query.
I don't think it's up to RDMS because SQLServer, Oracle, and Mysql behave the same way - error for first query, no error for second. I'm definitely missing something obvious, but I didn't find anything that describes why it works this way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is to do with the precedence of the comma operator. As stated in [the MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html)

> the precedence of the comma operator is less than of `INNER JOIN`, `CROSS
>   JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, and so on. If you mix comma joins with the other join
>   types when there is a join condition, an error of the form `Unknown
>   column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur`

You get the same results with the rewrite below (where the position of the `ON` clause makes clear the logical order of join operations)

**Fails**

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table1 a 
       INNER JOIN (table2 b 
                   INNER JOIN table3 c 
                     ON c.a_id = a.id ) -- error - a.id - invalid identifier 
         ON a.id = b.a_id
```

**Succeeds**

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table2 b 
       INNER JOIN (table1 a 
                   INNER JOIN table3 c 
                     ON c.a_id = a.id ) 
         ON a.id = b.a_id
```

In the one that succeeds `a` is first joined to `c` on `c.a_id = a.id` then the virtual table resulting from that join is joined to `b` on `a.id = b.a_id` which all works fine.

For the one that fails `b` is first attempted to be joined to `c` on `c.a_id = a.id` which is invalid as that references table `a`. The `ON` clause can only refer to the table immediately preceding it or one already brought in by a previous `ON` clause.

From the conditions `c.a_id = a.id` and `a.id = b.a_id` then `c.a_id=b.a_id` so you could change the join condition to that and it would work or you could of course also use a derived table or view to alter the precedence and ensure `a,b` were treated as a logically joined unit before joining onto `c`

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   table2 b, 
               table1 a) ba 
       INNER JOIN table3 c 
         ON ( c.a_id = ba.id ) 
WHERE  ( ba.id = ba.a_id )
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But it seems that your first example (marked as "fails") is not working due to syntax error (second `ON`), not because of invalid identifier. At least I'm able to execute that query `SELECT * FROM   table1 a  INNER JOIN table2 b   INNER JOIN table3 c ON ( c.a_id = a.id )` with Mysql 5.5.

Comment: @a1ex07 - MySQL requires some parentheses that are optional in SQL Server. Now added. In SQL Server the position of the `ON` clause is sufficient.